# Astyanax Cassandra host removed when keyspace already exists

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, astyanax

I'm using Astyanax 2.0.1 to connect to Cassandra.

I'm building my as AstyanaxContext such:

```
this.context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
                .forCluster(config.getClusterName())
                .forKeyspace(config.getKeyspace())
                .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(connectionPoolConfiguration)
                .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
                        .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.TOKEN_AWARE)
                )
                .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new Slf4jConnectionPoolMonitorImpl())
                .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());
        this.context.start();
```

After this, I try to create the keyspace if it doesn't already exist, I get the following:

```
AddHost: test-cassandra
  HostAdded: test-cassandra(192.168.2.111):9160
  BadRequestException: [host=test-cassandra(192.168.2.111):9160, latency=8(24), attempts=1]InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace 'test' does not exist)
```

Which is correct (I'll then proceed to create the keyspace). But if the keyspace does exist, I get:

```
AddHost: test-cassandra
HostAdded: test-cassandra(192.168.2.111):9160
AddHost: 127.0.0.1
HostAdded: 127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160
RemoveHost: test-cassandra
HostRemoved: test-cassandra(192.168.2.111):9160
```

This will create a wrong context, because it now starts pointing to localhost and eventually fails with

```
PoolTimeoutException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=2001(2001), attempts=1]Timed out waiting for connection
```

Any ideas if I'm configuring this wrong?

Comment: Does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259021/astyanax-cassandra-driver-removes-host-unexpectedly-during-batch-inserting ?